# What are these tiny, white, 6 petaled flowers that are growing on my lawn?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

I live in Canada, and it's pretty cold here still so I was surprised to see we have a BUNCH of tiny white flowers all over our lawn! All the usual flowers are blooming actually, but *these* ones I've never seen before. They're off-bluish white and are sort of clustered together- but in a line- on the top of their stem. Anyone know what they are?? Apologies for the dark picture by the way, my dad and I were out taking photos of the sunset when I noticed them.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Puschkin (one of my favorite spring bulbs). They've moved around within the botanical community and are now classified as Puschkinia scilloides. They're related to the true blue Scilla sibirica - Siberian Squills, which you may be familiar with. Here's a [photo](http://commons.hortipedia.com/images/1/16/Puschkinia_scilloides_photo_file_PDB_158KB.jpg) to confirm. Squirrels tend to move my bulbs around and they can appear many dozens of feet.. err, meters, away from where I planted them. If the flowers have recently opened you should be able to smell a very nice scent if you get really close to them.

To keep this little fellow coming back every year, either move it to a new non-mowed location after it's finished blooming or don't mow it down until the end of May. If you let it go to seed you'll get more blooms in a few years.

Comment: That definitely looks like it's worth keeping.